# UINavigationController autoresizing views behavior

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, view, dynamic-resizing

I've read in Apple's documentation about UINavigationController's resizing behavior and it hasn't been much of a problem until now.

I have the following code to set up my UINavigationController's view:

`navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420);`

and this is sufficient until the view is obscured by a modal view, at which point the view is resized to the default size somewhere between calls of `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` (as UINavigationController inherits from UIViewController).

I'm attempting to keep a banner visible above the UINavigationController (in the 40 by 320 space left available) but this banner is consistently obscured as described above.

Is there a way to surpress UINavigationController's resizing behavior without subclassing UIViewController myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In interface builder, you can uncheck the auto-resize checkbox.

In code, it's

```
[myNavController.view setAutoresizesSubviews: NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
myNavController.superview.autoresizesSubviews = NO
```

and obviously check `myNavController.autoresizingMask`

As a last resort, subclass its superview and reimplement layoutSubviews